# Prove $H_G=\cap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}$ is normal

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

Prove $H_G=\cap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}$ is normal for given $H\leq G$

My attempt is:
let $k\in G$ so $kH_Gk^{-1}=k(\cap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1})k^{-1}=\cap_{g\in G}kgHk^{-1}g^{-1}=\cap_{kg\in G}kgHk^{-1}g^{-1}=H_G$
is this the correct to prove this?

Comment: I think you meant $kg$ in the subscript, not $hg$, in which case yes that's correct.

Comment: corrected it thanks :)

Comment: There's a "$=$" missing.

Comment: Alternatively, prove that $H_G$ is the kernel of the action of $G$ by left multiplication on the left quotient set $G/H$.

Comment: Not exactly. You have unduly reversed $g^{-1}$ and $k^{-1}$ after the second "$=$".

Comment: Compare also with the proofs given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3084370/show-that-bigcap-a-in-g-a-h-a-1-is-a-normal-subgroup-of-g?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

$ \forall k \in G$

$kH_Gk^{-1}= k(\cap_{g \in G}gHg^{-1})k^{-1}$ = $ \cap_{g \in G}(kg)H(kg)^{-1}= H_{G} $ since, $kg \in G$

Comment: As @fitzcarraldo  pointed out in ta deleted comment the last equality requires the fact that $g\mapsto kg$ is onto $G$; it does not, as you say, follow from $kg\in G$. So I'd mark this as 6/10.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, I have inadvertedly deleted that comment (which I liked :-)), while I meant to cancel the other one of mine, where I said that the OP's proof is correct, which is not because of my last comment above.

Comment: Just wondering: If $g\mapsto kg$ is not onto, then $$\bigcap_{g \in G}(kg)H(kg)^{-1}$$ could be a bigger subgroup of $H$ than $H_G$,or? So $$k\left(\bigcap_{g \in G}gHg^{-1}\right)k^{-1}=\bigcap_{g \in G}(kg)H(kg)^{-1}$$ should also require $g\mapsto kg$ to be onto?

Comment: @Diger isn't $g \mapsto kg$ always onto? A preimage for $g_0 \in G$ would be $k^{-1}g_0$.

Comment: Probably I overcomplicated things. Since $G$ is a group $k^{-1}$ exists and $k^{-1}g_0$ is unique.